# getting error for node specific version install in home-brew

Tags: node.js, npm, package, homebrew

I'm trying to install rpm version 8.19.x and node version 16.x.x. I'm using a home-brew command `brew install npm@8` but it threw the following warning:

```
Warning: No available formula with the name "npm@8". Did you mean nfpm?
==> Searching for similarly named formulae and casks...
==> Formulae
nfpm

To install nfpm, run:
  brew install nfpm
```

I tried the following command to fix the issue but it was unresolved:

`git -C $(brew --repo homebrew/core) checkout master`

I looked up the available versions in brew but didn't get any result the code output is:

```
brew search npm@
==> Downloading https://formulae.brew.sh/api/formula.jws.json
#=#=#                                                                         
==> Formulae
npm                        pnpm                       nfpm                       nvm                        nim                        rpm                        qpm                        gpm                        cpm

==> Casks
ndm
```

Any advice would be appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managing Node installations via Homebrew isn't ideal.

[nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) allows you to easily install and manage multiple Node versions along with `npm`.